# Why did Elliot return to fsociety in the third episode of Mr. Robot?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

This is a plot summary from Wikipedia of the third episode of Mr. Robot:

> at the party, fsociety leaks Evil Corp's emails that incriminate Colby for covering up a toxic waste leak which caused leukemia in Elliot's father and Angela's mother. Elliot returns to fsociety.

Why did Elliot return to fsociety? Is this because he doesn't want Colby being sent to prison? Why couldn't he just continue his new "normal life"?

Comment: How much of the show have you watched? I'm not saying it "all becomes clear" if you continue watching... but a lot of stuff gets addressed if you do.

Comment: @catijaI watched 4 episodes so far.

Comment: Realistically, answering this question fully will require some major spoilers, which I'm guessing you don't really want to read.

Comment: @Catija They could as well be hidding behind spoiler blocks then. If he wants them to read is upto him but if they answer the question then they're the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He does not care about Colby's prison sentence. The reason for going back to fsociety is because his father and Angela's mother died because of the decisions made by inconsiderate people like Colby who work for E Corp and Elliot was a kid back then, now that facts are revealed on TV, Elliot wants revenge on E Corp for his father's death and goes back to fsociety with a plan.

While Elliot was watching news, he talks to himself.

> -My perfect maze crumbling before my eyes.
>
> -There's nothing to hide behind. I didn't think it existed, but there it was.
>
> -Is.
>
> -Mr. Robot finally found my bug.

Meaning, Mr. Robot found Elliot's bug to bring him back to fsociety by revealing the facts that caused his father's death.

Answer (score 2):

This might be the biggest cause of Elliot's return to F society, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Robot_(TV_series)):

> F Society's missions is to cancel all debts by taking down one of the largest corporations in the world, E Corp (known as "Evil Corp" by Elliot), which also happens to be All safe's biggest client.

Comment: but why then he didn't stay with them from the beginning? He returned to F society exactly after they incriminated Colby for covering up a toxic waste leak. He joined them against his will. I think this is somehow connected with his father.

Comment: Ya i think so.Might in the future episodes we will get to solve this mystery